# Question about constructing classifying space EG through $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the part about $K(G,1)\equiv BG$ space on page 89 of Algebraic Topology by Alan Hatcher.

"... Let $EG$ be the $\Delta$-complex whose $n$-simplices are the eordereed $(n+1)$-tuples $[g_0,\cdots, g_n]$ of elements of $G$. Such an $n$-simplex attaches to the $(n-1)$-simplices $[g_0,\cdots, \hat{g}_i,\cdots, g_n]$ in the obvious way, just as a standard simplex attaches to its faces.  The complex EG is contractible by the homotopy $h_t$ that slides each point $x\in [g_0,\cdots, g_n]$ along the line segment in $[e,g_0,\cdots, g_n]$ from $x$ to the vertex $[e]$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$. This is well-defined in $EG$ since when we restrict to a face $[g_0,\cdots, \hat{g}_i,\cdots, g_n]$ we have the linear deformation to $[e]$ in $[e,g_0,\cdots,\hat{g}_i,\cdots, g_n]$. Note that $h_t$ carries $[e]$ around the loop $[e,e]$, so $h_t$ is not actually a deformation retraction of $EG$ onto $[e]$."

1. Do vertices labeled with the same group element, say $e\in G$ for example, all identified eventually in the complex $EG$?   Suppose I have some $n$-simplex with $n$ bigger than the group order. Let's say 2-simplex $[0,1,1]$ for the case of $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Does this mean my 2-simplex is actually only 1-dimensional after all the gluing, in my eventual $E\mathbb{Z}_2$, through identifying the two vertices?
2. Might be related to the first question. Within each $n+1$-simplex $e,g_0,\cdots, g_n]$ shouldn't the point $e$ remain fixed throughout the process of $h_t$? I don't understand why the vertex labeled by $[e]$ is making a loop. I am also confused about what the 1-simplex $[e,e]$ is in the $n+1$-simplex, especially if none of $\{g_0,\cdots, g_n\}$ is $e$.

Thanks. Answering any of the two questions is a big help to me already.

Comment: Your post is a good example of our policy that to ask [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671). In this case, your post exhibits a knot of misunderstandings that is too entangled to handle with one answer. I'll address your first question in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question hints at some set theoretical misunderstandings and also some topological misunderstandings. Chapter 1 of Hatcher's book has heavy prerequisites in set theory and topology. I would suggest that you come back to this section *after* getting a more solid understanding of topology, including homotopy, in a more elementary book (for example Munkres Topology). And you also might benefit from skipping over this introductory chapter if you have not yet read about $\Delta$-complexes in the next chapter of Hatcher's book.

But meanwhile, let me say briefly what is going on in order to answer your first question within item 1.

As said, there is exactly one $n$-simplex for every $n+1$-tuple of elements of $G$. From set theory we know that an $n+1$-tuple of elements of $G$, formally, is a function whose domain is $\{0,1,...,n\}$ and whose codomain is $G$. The notation $[g_0,g_1,...,g_n]$ represents the $n$-simplex defined by the $n+1$-tuple which; in set theory, the $n$-tuple itself would be denoted $(g_0,g_1,...,g_n)$. Also from set theory, we know that two functions are equal if and only if they have equal values for every input. Therefore, $[g_0,g_1,...,g_n] = [h_0,h_1,...,h_n]$ if and only if $g_i=h_i$ for all $0 \le i \le n$. So in the case of two zero simplices we have $[g_0]=[h_0]$ if and only if $g_0=h_0$.

Let me point out one or two more things that you'll need to study to unwind some of the other confusions. What has not been explained yet, and what will be explained in the next chapter, is **what** the simplex $[g_0,g_1,...,g_n]$ actually **is**; in this introductory chapter, the author is depending on a *very* solid intuition. You'll most likely need to read into the next chapter on $\Delta$ complexes to learn the formalities and develop the intution, after which you will see that $[g_0,g_1,g_1]$ is indeed 2-dimensional, not 1-dimensional.

You really also need to learn more about paths and loops and homotopies, in under to understand to understand what it means that "$h_t$ carries $[e]$ around the loop $[e,e]$". In brief $h_t$ represents a continuous family of functions indexed by $t \in [0,1]$. And as $t$ varies, the varying point $h_t[e]$ will trace out a path which, yes, can form a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise and your help! Regarding the 2nd question, could you give an example of when a homotopy $h_t$ carries a point $v$ around a loop in a simplicial complex when $h_t$ is contracting a simplex towards the point $v$ just like here?   It's hard for me to imagine what's happening here. Appreciate it : ).